# How can I get started with functional programming using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I have a controlled component which updates inputs, using functional programming, I want to know if I need do this:

```
class ScreensEditSeries extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)  
    this.state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        status: '',
        genre: '',
        notes: ''
    }
}
...
handleChange = field => event => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,   //is necessary do this for return a new full state?
        [field] : event.target.value
    })
}
...
render(){
return(
...
                        Name: <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange('name')} className="form-control" /><br />
                        Status: {<span>&nbsp;</span>} 
                        <select value={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange('status')}>
                            {Object.keys(statsuser)
                                .map( key => <option key={key}>{statsuser[key]}</option>)}
                        </select><br/><br/>
                        Genre: {<span>&nbsp;</span>} 
                        <select value={this.state.genre} onChange={this.handleChange('genre')}>
                            {Object.keys(statsgenre)
                                .map(key => <option key={key}>{statsgenre[key]}</option>)}
                        </select><br/><br/>
                        Notes: <textarea type='text' value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleChange('notes')} className="form-control"></textarea><br />
...
)}
```

I am learning functional programming, and I think it's necessary to spread the state before updating to generate a new state, and not just update it. But this requires more memory and cpu process. Is it recommend to do that?

Comment: No it isnt. You can update only the key you need, react will keep the other keys unchanged.

Comment: "i want to know if i need do this": What happens when you don't do it? This is something you can easily work out.

Comment: @Andy, i know how to only change the key I need, and I know it works normally without doing as I showed in the example. The question I asked is about functional programming, which says that the object should not be changed, so what I did was to return a new state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not necessary, `setState` will only modify the variables given in the JSON you provide. In your case, only the `field` value's attribute will be modified.

Deconstructing your state isn't needed unless you want to modify a nested property.

Comment: Thanks man, my question was about immutability of data, and when we do setState(), we are changing the object, and the right thing would be to return a new object. But I think as I did in the example above, the state continues to mutate. My intention was to return a new state, as a copy of the old one, but now with attributes of different values. In the functional programming view, would giving a setState () attribute be wrong?